# Scheduled Run of batch not logging output to file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have two batch files with one calling the other

1)`test1.bat` having content `ping 127.0.0.1`

2) `test.bat` having content `call "D:\test1.bat"  >>output1.txt 2>>&1`

When I double click `test.bat`, as expected, the output is logged into `output1.txt`. however, when i schedule the same `test.bat` file, nothing gets logged.

I am scheduling this using the normal Windows task Scheduler. What am I missing here?

Comment: where is the working directory of the windows task scheduler? i think you will find your output1.txt there; or try `call "D:\test1.bat" >> D:\output1.txt 2>>&1`

Comment: oops yes! That was the issue. Please mention it as answer and I'll mark this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is the working directory of the windows task scheduler? i think you will find your output1.txt there; or try `call "D:\test1.bat" >> D:\output1.txt 2>>&1`